# Variable function name Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, metaprogramming

I'm sorting array:

```
myArray.sort(comparators.some_comparator);
```

and I have several comparator to choose from:

```
comparators = {

   asc_firstname_comparator : function(o1, o2){
    ...
   }

   desc_firstname_comparator : function(o1, o2){
    ...
   }

   etc...
}
```

I want to write function which returns certain comparator depending on input data. It should figure out comparator from string inputs, something like this:

```
function chooseComparator(field, order){

  return "comparators."+order+"_"+field+"_comparator";

}
```

So is it possible to pass only function name string to `sort()` method or I'll need to pass reference to correct comparator somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the subscript notation for indexing the javascript object (`obj.prop` is the same as `obj["prop"]`, but the latter way you can create property names dynamically):

```
function chooseComparator(field, order){ 

  return comparators[order+"_"+field+"_comparator"]; 

}
```

and yes, you have to pass a function object to the `sort()` function, just a name is not enough

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can create a closure instead of writing dozens of functions. Assuming `asc_firstname_comparator` means "sort by `x.firstname`",

```
function compareByProperty(field, order) {
   return function (o1, o2) {
      var retval;
      if (o1[field] > o2[field])
        retval = 1;
      else if (o1[field] < o2[field])
        retval = -1;
      else
        retval = 0;
      if (order === "desc")
        retval = -retval;
      return retval;
   }
}
...
myArray.sort(compareByProperty("firstname", "asc"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```
var comparators = {
   asc_firstname_comparator : function(o1, o2){ ... }
   desc_firstname_comparator : function(o1, o2){ ... }
};

Array.prototype.customSort(comparatorName) {
    this.sort(comparators[comparatorName]);
}

var myArray = [ ... ]; // define array
myArray.customSort("asc_firstname_comparator");
```